# F# Convert XML dynami to EXCEL with XMLProvider

Tags: f#

I am trying to convert xml file to excel.
I want to use with the **xmlProvider** tool but it seems that it cannot be generic,
I have some XML files are similar but with some small changes.
For example:

**The first XML file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OCEXPORT>
    <TABLE>
      <subjects>
        <sid>510</sid>
        <secondary_label></secondary_label>
        <person_id></person_id>
        <study>US-BID-018</study>
        <study_site>Hospital Vall d&apos;Hebron Barcelona</study_site>
        <group></group>
        <group_class></group_class>
        <gender></gender>
        <date_of_birth></date_of_birth>
        <date_created>2016-06-15 13:35:12.435342+00</date_created>
        <enrollment_date>2016-06-15 13:35:12.437+00</enrollment_date>
      </subjects>
      <subjects>
        <sid>509</sid>
        <secondary_label></secondary_label>
        <person_id></person_id>
        <study>US-BID-018</study>
        <study_site>Hospital Vall d&apos;Hebron Barcelona</study_site>
        <group></group>
        <group_class></group_class>
        <gender></gender>
        <date_of_birth></date_of_birth>
        <date_created>2016-06-15 11:20:02.662543+00</date_created>
        <enrollment_date>2016-06-15 11:20:02.664+00</enrollment_date>

          </subjects>
      </TABLE>
</OCEXPORT>
```

**The second one:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OCEXPORT>
    <TABLE>
      <subjects1>
        <sid>509</sid>
        <secondary>2</secondary>

        </subjects1>
      <subjects1>
        <sid>509</sid>
        <secondary>1</secondary>

        </subjects1>
      </TABLE>
</OCEXPORT>
```

The First level `<TABLE>` is the same in each file but the second level (`<subjects>`/`<subjects1>`)(the names and the number of the nodes) and the third level (the names and the number of the nodes) are different.

I need to build Excel file with some Sheets (for example with name of the node of the second level - **subjects**)
The columns name and values with the third level (sid,secondary_label and etc.)

Can I use with the xmlProvider to parse the XML files and export it to Excel file?

Comment: You can use the `sampleIsList` to generate a sample xml file with all the examples that you have.